# how can I delete a portion of a linked list?

Tags: java, java-8, linked-list

let's say my list is: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10

I want to delete a portion of this list. e.g. from index 1 to index 5.

so the list would change to: 1 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10

i'm using `java.util.LinkedList` :

`LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList();`

let's add the elements:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    list.add("" + i);
}
```

if I use the remove() function then I can only remove one element at a time. and every time indexes are updated. so I should do `list.remove(1);` six times.

is there any way to delete more than one element at once by giving start index and end index?

Comment: `list.removeAll(list.subList(1,6));`

Comment: "so I should do list.remove(1); six times" - Is that a problem?

Comment: @JimmyB yes! as i wrote in last line, i was wondering if there is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
list.subList(1, 6).clear();
```